# Error al leer de un txt cierta linea y pasarla como parametro a send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, txt

Estoy tratando de implementar un código simple utilizando Python con Seleniun,la cuestión es que tengo un txt con cierta linea adentro del cual quiero leerla y pasarla como parámetro a `send_keys` pero el resultado no es el que quiero:

```
from selenium import webdriver

with open('clientes.txt') as newfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(newfile, 1):
        if i == 1:
            break
    print(line)

chrome_opcions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\eglog\Proyectos\Panama\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_opcions)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(line)
```

El problema es que cuando obtiene el enlace de Google pone en el buscador la variable `line`, hasta ahí todo esta bien, eso es lo que se quiere,  pero auto seguido da click en la lupa y busca lo que le paso a través de `line` y yo no quiero buscar nada solo quiero que pase como parámetro `line`.

Si cambiáramos el código y pusiéramos ésto:

```
line = "alejandro@gmail.com"
chrome_opcions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\eglog\Proyectos\Panama\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_opcions)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(line)
```

entonces si pasa `line` normal y no da click en la lupa. Entonces mi pregunta es ¿por qué si leo de un txt la variable `line` el resultado no es el mismo?

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no hace click en nada, lo que simula es la pulsación de <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Ésto ocurre porque no estás enviando:

```
"alejandro@gmail.com"
```

envías:

```
"alejandro@gmail.com\n"
```

Tus líneas en el archivo tendrán [dependiendo de la plataforma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nueva_l%C3%ADnea) un EOL distinto:

```
"alejandro@gmail.com\n"
"alejandro@gmail.com\r\n"
"alejandro@gmail.com\r"
...
```

como bien comenta @braver si no asignamos un valor al argumento `newlines` de `open`, éste será `None` por defecto, lo que implica que cualquiera que sea el EOL será transformado a `\n`.

El carácter de nueva linea final se interpreta  como la pulsación de <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Por lo tanto el `send` equivale a escribir `alejandro@gmail.com` en la caja de búsqueda y pulsar <kbd>Enter</kbd> inmediatamente.

Ésto ocurre porque al iterar sobre las lineas de un fichero (`TextIOWrapper`) con un  `for`, que usa el protocolo iterador, o se llama a `readlines`, internamente se hace uso de la implementación en C del método `readline`.

`readline` retorna una cadena con los caracteres desde la posición actual del cursor hasta el siguiente carácter de nueva línea que encuentre, pero **no elimina el EOL de la cadena retornada**.

La solución es simplemente usar el método `str.rstrip()` y eliminar el carácter de nueva línea:

```
with open('clientes.txt') as newfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(newfile, 1):
        if i == 1:
            break
    line = line.rstrip()
    print(line)
```

Comment: muchas gracias eso mismo era,,,1000 gracias

Comment: Al leer lineas de un archivo, por defecto Python traslada el fin de linea ("\n", "\r\n", o "\r" dependiendo de la plataforma) a "\n", así que solamente envía "alejandro@gmail.com\n" (no depende de la plataforma). Eso lo explican en la documentación del parámetro *newline* de [*open*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: @braver cierto, corregido el desliz, gracias por el comentario.